# Selenium Web Driver Message validation in C#

Tags: c#, css, selenium

I am new to test automation. I want to get the value value of web element "message-success failed" which is "This customer name already exists".

[This is css look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HnRkW.png)

I tried with following code but go failed.

```
 Console.WriteLine(
     PropertiesCollection.driver
                         .FindElement(
                             By.ClassName("message-success failed"))
                               .GetCssValue("li"));
```

PropertiesCollection class is:

```
 class PropertiesCollection
    {
        // Auto-implemented property
        public static IWebDriver driver { set; get; }
    }
```

[This is the error I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/da88L.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First problem - you cannot pass multiple classes to the `ClassName` selector use a `.message-success.failed` CSS selector instead. To get the message text in this case, just get the `Text`:

```
Console.WriteLine(PropertiesCollection.driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".message-success.failed")).Text);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your alert reply. It was the answer I needed. Very much helpful.